# Get existing layer by name from map having multiple map/feature services in ArcGIS Javascript API 3.x

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, layers

I want to get existing layers from map and toggle on the visibility of the layers. The map has multiple services. I have the rest url for the service or the layer. And able to access the layer by using
*let fLayer = new FeatureLayer(url,....)*.

But when I tried on set visibility by using

*fLayer.setVisibility(true)
or
fLayer.show(*)

didn't work for me.

I have the information on the required layer names or ids in the respective services and the service urls.

Is there any possibility to get a layer from map using the service url and the layer name/id in that service? Please suggest.

Comment: I suggest you try remove it from the map and re-add it when needed.

Comment: But I think, to remove also I should pass layer information to map. I want to know how to  get required layer from map in the above condition.

Comment: can you share your code so we can help fixing it ?

Comment: Hi LMokrane, I got the solution and the same posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by doing similarly as in below link:
https://community.esri.com/thread/27093

I need to get the map service as dynamic layer from map, set the visibility of that dynamic layer and send the array of ids of the required layers inside it for setVisibleLayers.